# Read stream OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, streaming, ip-camera

I'd like to stream my IPCamera using OpenCV in Python. I succeeded doing this by using urllib and reading image by image from http://192.168.10.1/snapshot.cgi?user=admin&pwd=. In browser, this URL just shows a 'live' image. However it isn't really live anymore since I get a few seconds delay and also low FPS (~4) using this method.

I also found a good stream, high FPS and almost no delay in browser. (http://192.168.10.1/video/liveplg.asp Note: this is not an URL to the raw stream, since there is an interface with it) I had to install a Firefox plugin before I was able to view this stream (npIPCamPlug.dll). In html-file the stream is shown in an object element with type application/x-ipcam.

Now my question is: can I somehow get this high FPS stream in OpenCV?

Comment: can you provide the protocol that the camera is using - TCP/UDP. Also check what image resolution is being transmitted.

Comment: How can I see what protocol the camera uses? The resolution is 720p

Answer (score 0):

You can check the URL with iSpy(open source wonderful software).

In my case ( Wiseup P2P WiFi Camera )

cv2.VideoCapture("http://admin@192.168.10.1:80/videostream.asf?user=admin&pwd=&resolution=64&rate=0")